# How to host the files in public port and access from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

Am very new to ubuntu and am using ubuntu for Jenkins. I have referred the below link and configured jenkins in ubuntu machine.

https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-and-use-jenkins-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Now, am stucking with host my files(like IIS in windows machines) in ubuntu machine in the port 8081. Since, Port 8080 is used  by Jenkins.

While i searched, i found that we can't host the files in the ubuntu machine like windows machine. I have tried to create new port by creating rules. But my firewall has disabled and am unable to connect the ubuntu machine. Am trying to recover it.

Link i followed is https://askubuntu.com/questions/624214/open-ports-for-public

So, could anyone please help me about how to host or bring my files in the port 8081 and access it(**Example:** http://localhost:8081/index.html) from ubuntu machine?

Thanks in advance!!! Please guide me on this by share your knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

Install apache2 and chang the port to 8081

Comment: Then how the jenkins configured in port 8080? What is the default web server installed in ubuntu machine? how to copy the files from windows machine to ubuntu machine and accessed from the port 8081?